# Transform methods with AsyncCallbacks to Task<Result> methods

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-8

would like to change my methods from HttpWebRequest.BeginGetRequestStream and HttpWebRequest.BeginGetResponse to methods which use async and Tasks. I need to use these methods because I work on Windows Phone and other methods like GetRequestStream which is not async are not available on this platform.

This is my method DownloadString:

```
private static Action<string> completed;

    public static void DownloadString(Action<string> c)
    {
        completed = c;

        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri("linkhere", UriKind.Absolute));
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/536.5 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/19.0.1084.52 Safari/536.5Accept: */*";
        request.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
        request.BeginGetRequestStream(RequestCallback, request);
    }

    private static void RequestCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)ar.AsyncState;

        Stream postStream = request.EndGetRequestStream(ar);
        //some post data

        request.BeginGetResponse(ResponseCallback, request);
    }

    private static void ResponseCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)ar.AsyncState;
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.EndGetResponse(ar);

        Stream streamResponse = response.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader streamReaders = new StreamReader(streamResponse);
        string content = streamReaders.ReadToEnd();
        streamResponse.Close();
        streamReaders.Close();
        response.Close();

        completed.Invoke(content);
    }
```

For the next step I used the following link:
[Converting Callback Functions to Task Pattern](http://dotnetspeak.com/2013/04/converting-callback-functions-to-task-pattern)
Now I want to have a wrapper method like this:

```
 public async static Task<string> DownloadWithoutAction()
    {
        TaskCompletionSource<string> tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<string>();
        var task = tcs.Task;
        Action<string> callback = tcs.SetResult;
        await Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            DownloadString(callback);
        }, TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent);
        return await Task.FromResult(task.Result);
    }
```

The Problem: 
This does not work because the callbacks are async and so the thread stops before the callbacks are fired. This is only my guess. How can I work around?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use FromAsync method from TaskFactory:

```
var request = HttpWebRequest.CreateHttp("http://url");
var stream = await Task.Factory.FromAsync<Stream>(request.BeginGetRequestStream, request.EndGetRequestStream, TaskCreationOptions.None);
var response = (HttpWebResponse)(await Task.Factory.FromAsync<WebResponse>(request.BeginGetResponse, request.EndGetResponse, TaskCreationOptions.None));
```

The method using Tasks could be:

```
private async Task<string> DownloadString()
{
    var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri("linkhere", UriKind.Absolute));
    request.Method = "POST";
    request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/536.5 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/19.0.1084.52 Safari/536.5Accept: */*";
    request.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";

    using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)(await Task.Factory.FromAsync<WebResponse>(request.BeginGetResponse, request.EndGetResponse, TaskCreationOptions.None)))
    using (var streamResponse = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        return await streamResponse.ReadToEndAsync();
    }
}
```

Comment: The question is about methods using a callback model of asynchronous programming, which is subtly different from the asynchronous model used by `Task.FromAsync`.

Comment: In the first line he indicates that want to change his methods to use Tasks. With the lines I've indicate, he can change his implementation to use Tasks.

Comment: He wants to change *a method that accepts a callback* to a method that uses tasks.  Your approach doesn't allow for that.

Comment: In my edit, you can see how he can change the method for use Tasks.

Comment: Once again, the question is how to take a method that accepts a callback and generate a task based on the completion of that callback.  This isn't doing that.  Stephen's answer is.  That is how you generate a Task based on the completion of a method accepting a callback.

Comment: @user3570696 if you need the request stream, you have to use: var stream = await Task.Factory.FromAsync<Stream>(request.BeginGetRequestStream, request.EndGetRequestStream, TaskCreationOptions.None);

Comment: Ok thanks. I'll try it out and I will tell you later

Comment: @Servy At the start of his question, he is asking for change his method to use tasks. Then he says that using the example has tried to make a wrapper, but it doesnt work. I've answered his first question, and it's valid.

Comment: Ok I tried, did you check if it is working? For me it is not :(. When I add Debug.WriteLine ..., I don't get any output. It is the same for the solution of Stephen Cleary.

Comment: I've tested it downloading HTML from google.com an it is working (a GET request without headers). Show your final code.

Comment: My solution: public static async Task<string> DownloadString()
        {
            var request = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(new Uri("http://www.google.de", UriKind.Absolute));

            request.Method = "GET";

            using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)(await Task.Factory.FromAsync<WebResponse>(request.BeginGetResponse, request.EndGetResponse, TaskCreationOptions.None)))
            using (var streamResponse = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                return await streamResponse.ReadToEndAsync();
            }
        }

Comment: And the way i am calling it: MessageBox.Show(YouTubeHelper.DownloadString().Result);

Comment: You shouldread the following post: http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.HTML  
To get this work the code should be:
    var result = await YouTubeHelper.DownloadString();
    MessageBox.Show(resut);

Answer (score 3):

First, I strongly recommend that you upgrade to [`HttpClient`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Net.Http/).

But if you want to do it the harder way, then you would do something like this:

```
public static Task<string> DownloadStringAsync()
{
  TaskCompletionSource<string> tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<string>();
  DownloadString(result => tcs.SetResult(result));
  return tcs.Task;
}
```

Comment: Hi,thanks for the fast reply. The problem is, that HttpClient doesn't exist in the Windows Phone Framework.

Comment: @user3570696 Yes it does. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2013/02/18/portable-httpclient-for-net-framework-and-windows-phone.aspx

Comment: @user3570696: If you followed the link to `HttpClient` in my answer, you'd see it's pointing to a NuGet package that clearly states it supports WPA 8.1 and WP SL 7.5 (in other words, every WP platform that supports `async` also supports `HttpClient`).